# Launching JavaFX application from eclipse or jar - double sized memory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx

When i'm running my javafx application from eclipse (oxygen/maven 3.3) it needs about 500mb memory. After a maven build it needs about 1GB when i start the jar file.

I always do the same routine... Here's my setup:

1. Eclipse: Oxygen 2 with Maven 3.3.9 -> starting my JavaFX Application, do my routine -> look at taskmanager and visualvm: ~500mb
2. Doing a maven build from outside eclipse (maven 3.6.0): It generates a jar file into a specific directory -> starting the jar file with java -jar app.jar -> doing my routine -> look at taskmanager and visualvm: ~1GB

I expect the same memory usage in both situations. I really do not understand this. Thanks for help.

Comment: I think you use something like this in your POM.
`<initialHeapSize>1024</initialHeapSize>` 
So when you create the jar/exe it will start with 1GB

Comment: thanks, that could be a solution... i also found out, that there is a huge difference in using java and javaw. I figured out that eclipse running javaw instead of java command. I couldn't believe that is so much difference between these two commands.